# exit if / for on success

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, for-loop

I created a script for compare values from two files and output a messges on both cases (success or failure). But then I realized, even on success the script goes on and on to compare the main variable (jbid) with all other variables (bsid) in the second file, which I don't want. I want the second for loop to end when the "if" encounters a success.

I'm comparing 'jbsid' from tmpcsv2 with 'bsid' from file bkid.

```
for jbid in `cat tmpcsv`; do #1st Loop

    for bsid in `cat bkid`; do #2nd Loop

        ckid=`echo $bsid | cut -d "," -f1`
        jbsiz=`echo $bsid | cut -d "," -f2`

        if [ "$jbid" -eq "$ckid" ]; then
          printf "There's a match at $ckid\n"  
        else
          printf "No Match Found at $ckid\n"
        fi

    done

    printf "Check for ID $jbid done\n"
    sleep 2
done
```

I may be using a wrong way of doing this and open for a shorter/crisper form too !

Comment: Simply add `break 2` after `then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add "break" in the true conditional branch.

Also, I was confused about the comparison between jbid and ckid. What is jbsiz for?

```
for jbid in `cat tmpcsv`; do #1st Loop

    for bsid in `cat bkid`; do #2nd Loop

        ckid=`echo $bsid | cut -d "," -f1`
        jbsiz=`echo $bsid | cut -d "," -f2`

        if [ "$jbid" -eq "$ckid" ]; then
          printf "There's a match at $ckid\n"
          break   
        else
          printf "No Match Found at $ckid\n"
        fi

    done

    printf "Check for ID $jbid done\n"
    sleep 2
done
```

Comment: Yes.. I forgot about that earlier... I have modified my script and now it's working fine....But, thanks for quick reply !!

jbsiz -> job size !

My new script -
for jbid in `cat tmpcsv2`
do
 for bsid in `cat 1bkpsid`
 do
  ckid=`echo $bsid | cut -d "," -f1`
  jbsiz=`echo $bsid | cut -d "," -f2`
  if [ $jbid == $ckid ]
  then
   printf "There's a match of $jbid and $ckid\n"
   sleep 2
   break
  else
   printf ""
   #printf "No Match Found for $jbid at $ckid\n"
  fi
 done
printf "Check for ID $jbid done\n"
sleep 2
done

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ "$jbid" -eq "$ckid" ]; then
    printf "There's a match at $ckid\n"   
    break
```

This should make the second for loop end on a match.

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ "$jbid" -eq "$ckid" ]; then
          printf "There's a match at $ckid\n"
          break   
        else
          printf "No Match Found at $ckid\n"
        fi
```

Add break between `then - else`; like the code above.

Comment: Sorry fellas... all 3 of you are correct..... but I can choose only one (I tried but allows only one correct answer!) 

Thanks a lot of replying so quickly !